# MongoDB query taking too much time to retrieve data

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have one collection with 3 million documents and the following indexes:

> { ts : 1 } , {u_id: 1}

Note that these are two separate ascending indexes, not a compound index.

When I run this query:

> db.collection.find({u_id: 'user'}).sort({ts : -1}).skip(0).limit(1)

it takes +100ms. I have the following logs:

> 2017-04-15T06:42:01.147+0000 I COMMAND  [conn783] query
>   db.collection query: { orderby: { ts: -1 }, $query: {
>   u_id: "user-ki-id } } planSummary: IXSCAN { u_id:
>   1 }, IXSCAN { u_id: 1 } ntoreturn:1 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:10795
>   docsExamined:10795 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0
>   writeConflicts:0 numYields:86 nreturned:1 reslen:771 locks:{ Global: {
>   acquireCount: { r: 174 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 87 } },
>   Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 87 } } } **246ms**

A few notable points about the problem:

- There is no other load on MongoDB i.e. no other queries which take +100ms
- This is happening every minute; I think I am storing data every minute so this is happening
- The query flow is to first run the read query (as above), then the next query is a bulk insertion. This flow is repeated every one minute.

So my questions are:

- Why is it happening? Are there any design flaws in my indexing?
- Might it be worthwhile to change indexing to be descending, like {ts: -1}? What is the actual difference between these indexes?
- According to MongoDB documentation, when you are doing sorting with order then result will pick from disk not "in-memory". Does this explain why it takes +100ms?
- Can anybody explain me profiling log in detail level?
- Is it desired behaviour of MongoDB?

The same thing is also happening when I run a range search on this collection; this takes 3-5 seconds.

**EDIT:** 
I have only add {u_id: 1, ts: -1} index. Remove all other index (except _id). Still in first time query execution taking +100ms. This should not happen.
Query:

> db.getCollection('locations') .find({u_id: "USR-WOWU"})
>   .sort({ts: -1}) .explain(true)

OutPut::

> /* 1 */ {
>       "queryPlanner" : {
>           "plannerVersion" : 1,
>           "namespace" : "db_name.collection_name",
>           "indexFilterSet" : false,
>           "parsedQuery" : {
>               "user_id" : {
>                   "$eq" : "USR-WOWU"
>               }
>           },
>           "winningPlan" : {
>               "stage" : "FETCH",
>               "inputStage" : {
>                   "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                   "keyPattern" : {
>                       "u_id" : 1.0,
>                       "ts" : -1.0
>                   },
>                   "indexName" : "u_id_1_ts_-1",
>                   "isMultiKey" : false,
>                   "isUnique" : false,
>                   "isSparse" : false,
>                   "isPartial" : false,
>                   "indexVersion" : 1,
>                   "direction" : "forward",
>                   "indexBounds" : {
>                       "u_id" : [ 
>                           "[\"USR-WOWU\", \"USR-WOWU\"]"
>                       ],
>                       "ts" : [ 
>                           "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
>                       ]
>                   }
>               }
>           },
>           "rejectedPlans" : []
>       },
>       "executionStats" : {
>           "executionSuccess" : true,
>           "nReturned" : 164,
>           "executionTimeMillis" : 119,
>           "totalKeysExamined" : 164,
>           "totalDocsExamined" : 164,
>           "executionStages" : {
>               "stage" : "FETCH",
>               **"nReturned" : 164,**
>               **"executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 120,**
>               "works" : 165,
>               "advanced" : 164,
>               "needTime" : 0,
>               "needYield" : 0,
>               "saveState" : 3,
>               "restoreState" : 3,
>               "isEOF" : 1,
>               "invalidates" : 0,
>               "docsExamined" : 164,
>               "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
>               "inputStage" : {
>                   "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                   "nReturned" : 164,
>                   "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
>                   "works" : 165,
>                   "advanced" : 164,
>                   "needTime" : 0,
>                   "needYield" : 0,
>                   "saveState" : 3,
>                   "restoreState" : 3,
>                   "isEOF" : 1,
>                   "invalidates" : 0,
>                   "keyPattern" : {
>                       "u_id" : 1.0,
>                       "ts" : -1.0
>                   },
>                   "indexName" : "u_id_1_ts_-1",
>                   "isMultiKey" : false,
>                   "isUnique" : false,
>                   "isSparse" : false,
>                   "isPartial" : false,
>                   "indexVersion" : 1,
>                   "direction" : "forward",
>                   "indexBounds" : {
>                       "u_id" : [ 
>                           "[\"USR-WOWU\", \"USR-WOWU\"]"
>                       ],
>                       "ts" : [ 
>                           "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "keysExamined" : 164,
>                   "dupsTested" : 0,
>                   "dupsDropped" : 0,
>                   "seenInvalidated" : 0
>               }
>           },
>           "allPlansExecution" : []
>       },
>       "serverInfo" : {
>           "host" : "manish",
>           "port" : 22022,
>           "version" : "3.2.13",
>           "gitVersion" : "23899209cad60aaafe114f6aea6cb83025ff51bc"
>       },
>       "ok" : 1.0 }

Please copy above jSON and format into any editor.

After above query, the next same query will response with in ~2 ms. But When I do  few insertion then after one min same thing will be repeated. (1st time query will take time +100ms and then it will take ~2ms.)

Is something missing or anything is required to configuration in my mongoDB ??

Comment: Could you cite your source for the question: 'when you are doing sorting with order then result will pick from disk not "in-memory" '. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#sort-and-index-use
Let me correct if I am misinterpreting

Comment: @Vince : thanks for correction!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it happening

The `docsExamined:10795` and `hasSortStage:1`  portions of this log line indicates that the query is scanning 10,795 from disk and then sorting the results in memory. A guide on interpreting log lines can be found [here](http://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#comparing-log-lines).

A performance improvement can likely be gained by [indexing this query to avoid the in-memory sort](http://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#sorting-efficiently).

For this query, you should try creating the index `{ 'u_id' : 1, 'ts' : -1 }`.

> Is it really worthfull if I will change indexing like {ts: -1} in descending order.

Indexes can be read in either direction, so the index order isn't super important on single field indexes. However, sort ordering can be very important in [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order).

#### Updated

Based on the explain plan, the query is now properly using the index to read the results from the index in order, which avoids the in-memory sort. It looks like this knocked off ~100ms off the query.

However, it looks like this query is no longer using `.skip(0).limit(1)`. Can you add these back in and see if performance improves?

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your deployment; this behavior seems normal for queries that are not fully indexed.

Re-running the exact same query will be quick because the existing results ("[the working set](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/diagnostics/#what-is-a-working-set)") are already stored in memory. Inserting new data can make the results of the query change, meaning the results may need to be read back into memory again.

Comment: I have rebuild index with -1 (only field index) but  still getting issue. Now I will try compound index then let you know what happen... :)

Comment: Nothing improvement!! I have done with following index
1st Try : {u_id: 1} {ts: 1}
2nd Try : {u_id: 1} {ts: -1} 3rd Try :{u_id: 1} {ts: -1}  {u_id: 1, ts: -1} ;; 4th Try :{u_id: 1} {ts: 1}  {u_id: 1, ts: -1}.......

Comment: @ManishTrivedi On that fourth try, with the compound index `{u_id: 1, ts: -1}`, that should have made a difference. Does the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) show any difference?

Comment: @ManishTrivedi Would you be able to share a new log line now that these indexes have been built? As Vince suggested, running an explain is also helpful for determining how the database is using indexes

Comment: I really appreciate your help! :) :)  I have added query planner logs in question. This time I have tried with only compound Index. (I need few more fields for index regarding range search but do it later. First I want to solve this issue... :( )

Comment: Okay, I think first call of MongoDB will take time to get data from disk. (in millis) I have restarted mongo-Server then now working perfectly smooth after first db-call.